# How to merge similar table in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, merge, phpmyadmin, mybb

How to merge similar tables into one table in `phpMyAdmin`?

- I have 1 backup table `mybb_threads_bak`
- I have 1 incorrect table `mybb_threads`

I want to import and merge and update my table `mybb_threads_bak` into incorrect table without showing any errors

In other words i want import `mybb_threads_bak` table into `mybb_threads` table .

Help me and get best query [code](http://barnamenevis.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=122662&d=1408967322) :)

Comment: So if the backup is proper, truncate the table that has the incorrect data, then import the sql file that has the correct data into that table.

Comment: You can export your backup table and choose the update option instead the standard insert option. Then import the export-file into your incorrect table. Its works only if both tables have still the same structure.

Comment: No. my backup is 20day ago and my user send posts in my site .i want add mybb_threads_bak to mybb_threads

Comment: Wen inport old table say this error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO mybb_threads FROM  mybb_threads_bak;

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO mybb_threads SELECT * FROM mybb_threads_bak;

"Wen inport old table say this error: #1062 - Duplicate entry '6' for key 'PRIMARY' – abbas Aug 28 '14 at 19:48 "

When there is partly duplicate data use INSERT IGNORE INTO...